# SQL sample connection string that can be Re-used

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, airflow

It's better to have some `SQL`  connection string examples handy that someone can read , relate and re-use in `airflow.cfg` file.

I had a very hard time finding those in the official documentation of airflow.

Could anyone share the same..?

Answer (score 0):

I have few examples for `SQLite` , `MYSQL` and `PostgreSQL`

SQLite:-

```
sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////home/rahul/airflow/airflow.db
```

In the above example we just need to replace the path with the path where your `SQLite` DB file is stored.

MYSQL:-

```
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/airflow
```

In the above example first `root` is the `username` of MYSQL and next `root` is the `password` for that user and since the `default port` for MYSQL is `3306` so it's pointing to `localhost:3306` please change it if you're pointing to some `remote DB` and `airflow` is the DB name.
So make sure you have MYSQL db running with `root` user and `root` password with DB name `airflow` in it in order to re-use the above snippet.

PostgreSQL:-

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@localhost:5432/airflow
```

In the above example first `airflow` is the `username` of PostgreSQL and next `airflow` is the `password` for that user and since the `default port` for PostgreSQL is `5432` so it's pointing to `localhost:5432` please change it if you're pointing to some `remote DB` and `airflow` is the DB name.
So make sure you have PostgreSQL db running with `airflow` user and `airflow` password with DB name `airflow` in it in order to re-use the above snippet.

If anyone is having example connection string for other SQL DBs please share

Thanks

Comment: This all listed in the docs https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/initialize-database.html